# Meteor Client Sign Placer

Tags: java, client, minecraft

I want to build own module for meteor client, I want to it auto placed signs aroung player, but I cant get it work, sorry for errors in the code (I am bad in java).

Ill provide some files:
Addon.java:

```
package com.AndrexYT.AutoAdvertiser;

import com.AndrexYT.AutoAdvertiser.commands.CommandGithub;
import com.AndrexYT.AutoAdvertiser.commands.CommandStore;
import com.AndrexYT.AutoAdvertiser.modules.ModuleSignPlacer;
import com.mojang.logging.LogUtils;
import meteordevelopment.meteorclient.addons.MeteorAddon;
import meteordevelopment.meteorclient.commands.Commands;
import meteordevelopment.meteorclient.systems.hud.Hud;
import meteordevelopment.meteorclient.systems.hud.HudGroup;
import meteordevelopment.meteorclient.systems.modules.Category;
import meteordevelopment.meteorclient.systems.modules.Modules;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

public class Addon extends MeteorAddon {
    public static final Logger LOG = LogUtils.getLogger();
    public static final Category CATEGORY = new Category("AutoAdvertiser");
    public static final HudGroup HUD_GROUP = new HudGroup("AutoAdvertiserGroup");

    @Override
    public void onInitialize() {
        LOG.info("Initializing Meteor AutoAdvertiser");

        // Modules
        Modules.get().add(new ModuleSignPlacer()); // Add ModuleSignPlacer

        // Commands
        Commands.add(new CommandGithub());
        Commands.add(new CommandStore());

        // HUD
        //Hud.get().register(Hud.INFO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegisterCategories() {
        Modules.registerCategory(CATEGORY);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPackage() {
        return "com.AndrexYT.AutoAdvertiser";
    }
}
```

ModuleSignPlacer:

```
package com.AndrexYT.AutoAdvertiser.modules;

// Import the necessary classes
import meteordevelopment.meteorclient.systems.modules.Category;
import meteordevelopment.meteorclient.systems.modules.Module;
import meteordevelopment.meteorclient.systems.modules.settings.*;
import net.minecraft.block.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.block.entity.SignBlockEntity;
import net.minecraft.text.LiteralText; // Import LiteralText from net.minecraft.text
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;

public class ModuleSignPlacer extends Module {

    private final SettingGroup sgGeneral = settings.getDefaultGroup();

    // Settings
    private final IntSetting range = sgGeneral.add(new IntSetting.Builder()
        .name("range")
        .description("The maximum distance from the player to place signs.")
        .defaultValue(6)
        .min(1)
        .sliderMin(1)
        .sliderMax(6)  // Maximum range set to 6 blocks
        .build()
    );

    private final StringSetting signText = sgGeneral.add(new StringSetting.Builder()
        .name("sign-text")
        .description("The text to be displayed on the signs.")
        .defaultValue("Hello, world!")
        .build()
    );

    public ModuleSignPlacer() {
        super(Category.PLAYER, "SignPlacer", "Places signs with customizable text within a specified range.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivate() {
        // Get player's position
        BlockPos playerPos = new BlockPos(mc.player.getX(), mc.player.getY(), mc.player.getZ());

        // Calculate random direction and distance within the specified range
        double angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
        double distance = Math.random() * range.get();

        // Calculate sign position
        double x = playerPos.getX() + distance * Math.cos(angle);
        double z = playerPos.getZ() + distance * Math.sin(angle);
        double y = playerPos.getY(); // Keep the sign at the same height as the player

        // Place the sign block
        mc.world.setBlockState(new BlockPos(x, y, z), Blocks.OAK_SIGN.getDefaultState());

        // Set the sign text
        SignBlockEntity sign = (SignBlockEntity) mc.world.getBlockEntity(new BlockPos(x, y, z));
        if (sign != null) {
            // Check if the block entity is not null
            sign.setText(new LiteralText(signText.get()));
            sign.markDirty(); // Mark the sign as dirty
        }

        // Print a message in the chat
        mc.player.sendMessage(new LiteralText("Sign placed with text: " + signText.get()), false);
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "fabric-loom" version "1.5-SNAPSHOT"
}

sourceCompatibility = targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

archivesBaseName = project.archives_base_name
version = project.mod_version
group = project.maven_group

repositories {
    maven {
        name = "Meteor Dev Releases"
        url = "https://maven.meteordev.org/releases"
    }
    maven {
        name = "Meteor Dev Snapshots"
        url = "https://maven.meteordev.org/snapshots"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Fabric
    minecraft "com.mojang:minecraft:${project.minecraft_version}"
    mappings "net.fabricmc:yarn:${project.yarn_mappings}:v2"
    modImplementation "net.fabricmc:fabric-loader:${project.loader_version}"

    // Meteor
    modImplementation "meteordevelopment:meteor-client:${project.meteor_version}"
}

processResources {
    filesMatching("fabric.mod.json") {
        expand "version": project.version, "mc_version": project.minecraft_version
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    it.options.encoding("UTF-8")
}
```

Tree of the project folder:

```
├───.github
│   └───workflows
├───.gradle
│   ├───8.3
│   │   ├───checksums
│   │   ├───dependencies-accessors
│   │   ├───executionHistory
│   │   ├───fileChanges
│   │   ├───fileHashes
│   │   └───vcsMetadata
│   ├───buildOutputCleanup
│   ├───loom-cache
│   │   ├───minecraftMaven
│   │   │   └───net
│   │   │       └───minecraft
│   │   │           └───minecraft-merged-3848b19350
│   │   │               ├───1.19.4-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_19_4.1.19.4+build.1-v2
│   │   │               └───1.20.4-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_20_4.1.20.4+build.2-v2
│   │   └───remapped_mods
│   │       └───net_fabricmc_yarn_1_19_4_1_19_4_build_1_v2
│   │           ├───meteordevelopment
│   │           │   └───meteor-client
│   │           │       └───0.5.6-SNAPSHOT
│   │           └───net
│   │               └───fabricmc
│   │                   └───fabric-api
│   │                       └───fabric-resource-loader-v0
│   │                           └───0.11.17+707e4d1b4f
│   └───vcs-1
├───.idea
├───build
│   ├───classes
│   │   └───java
│   │       └───main
│   │           └───com
│   │               └───AndrexYT
│   │                   └───AutoAdvertiser
│   │                       ├───commands
│   │                       ├───hud
│   │                       └───modules
│   ├───devlibs
│   ├───generated
│   │   └───sources
│   │       ├───annotationProcessor
│   │       │   └───java
│   │       │       └───main
│   │       └───headers
│   │           └───java
│   │               └───main
│   ├───libs
│   ├───loom-cache
│   │   └───remapped_working
│   ├───resources
│   │   └───main
│   │       └───assets
│   │           └───template
│   └───tmp
│       ├───compileJava
│       │   └───compileTransaction
│       │       ├───backup-dir
│       │       └───stash-dir
│       ├───jar
│       └───remapJar
├───gradle
│   └───wrapper
└───src
    └───main
        ├───java
        │   └───com
        │       └───AndrexYT
        │           └───AutoAdvertiser
        │               ├───commands
        │               ├───hud
        │               └───modules
        └───resources
            └───assets
                └───template
```

How can I fix that? Also In future I want to add frames and maps placer, so it would place map arts in nether, on 2B2T. Thank you.

Comment: Where are your errors?